# Problema Web Scrapping (No aparecen todos los DIV)

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-scrapping

Estoy tratando de hacer scrapping a esta pagina:
https://tracking-unificado.blue.cl/, la idea es colocar un Numero de Transporte, y obtener su tracking, pero no me aparecen todos los "divs" cuando hago el "parser"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

OT = '7643401872'
base_url = 'https://tracking-unificado.blue.cl/'
full_url = f'{base_url}?n_seguimiento={OT}'
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get(full_url)
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]')
element.click()
pedido_obtenido = requests.get(full_url)
text = pedido_obtenido.text
soup = bs(text, "html.parser")
a = soup.find_all('div')
```

en "a" no estan los div del Historial de Segumiento que necesito extraer y no veo como obtenerlos :/

Comment: Dado que los elementos que deseas se generan dinamicamente requests no sirve de nada,  es una libreria http, no puede ejecutar javascript. Usar Selenium antes de requests no te sirve, son dos sesiones y peticiones independientes.. En vez de usar requests, usa selenium para obtener los divs o el código html de toda la pagina después del click en  el botón.

Comment: Como comentan mas arriba, ingrese a tu pagina y validé el xpath usado y no me marca nada, te recomiendo //div[@class='HeaderContainer']//input[@placeholder='Ingresa tu N° de OS'] o si te complican los localizadores usar la extension selectorhub. Saludos.